# Batch Script - Transfering video every day to next folder

Tags: batch-file, video, directory

I'm recording video from ip-cam via VLC. The length of a recorded video - 1 hour. At this moment, all videos are recorded in a single directory, it's very inconvenient. I'd like to make subfolders in the main folder and renumber it as the days of the month, ie 01, 02, 03 ... to 31. Can I use a batch script that at 00:00:01 automatically transfer the video records to the next day's directory? Ie each day were recorded only 24 files/hours (01 - 24 hours 02 - 24, 03 - 24 hours, etc.)
Below is my current batch script:

```
@echo off
SET C=1
:L

set hour=%time:~0,2%
if "%hour:~0,1%" == " " set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
set min=%time:~3,2%
if "%min:~0,1%" == " " set min=0%min:~1,1%
set secs=%time:~6,2%
if "%secs:~0,1%" == " " set secs=0%secs:~1,1%

set year=%date:~-4%
set month=%date:~3,2%
if "%month:~0,1%" == " " set month=0%month:~1,1%
set day=%date:~0,2%
if "%day:~0,1%" == " " set day=0%day:~1,1%
set datetimef=%day%.%month%.%year%__%hour%.%min%

vlc -vvv rtsp://10.10.22.225/h264 --sout=file/mp4:"D:\IP-CAM\%c%-%datetimef%.mp4" --run-time=3600 --play-and-exit --qt-start-

minimized 
SET /a C+=1
IF %c% GTR 744 SET C=1
goto :L
```

Comment: `md "%day%"`  `move *.mp4 "%day%"` OK? Start this with [Windows Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

How about you establish the directories 01..31 in your output directory (which I'll assume is `D:\IP-CAM\` for want of further information, then modify your vlc line to

```
vlc -vvv rtsp://10.10.22.225/h264 --sout=file/mp4:"D:\IP-CAM\%DAY%\%c%-%datetimef%.mp4" --run-time=3600 --play-and-exit --qt-start-minimized
```

which should fill today's directory with today's files, tomorrow with tomorrows, and so on.

Might also be an idea to rethink your naming system. ddmmyyyy is all very sensible, but confuses those who use mmddyyyy. yyyymmdd should be understood by most except those detemined to remain confused - and it automatically sorts itself into date-order (although your %c% prefix with the rather odd limit of 744 may interfere there...)